# How do you disallow Drag and Drop between two JTables?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I have two JTables, and they are set up so that you can drag and drop the rows within each JTable.  The problem is that it lets me drag a row from one JTable to the other JTable, and I am trying to figure out how to stop that.  I only want the user to be able to drag and drop a row within that same JTable.

In other words, when I drag a row outside the current table and hover the mouse over the empty panel space, the mouse cursor displays a circle with a diagonal line through it, which is what I want.  *However*, when I drag the mouse over the other table, it displays the small rectangular "drop" icon, which is what I am trying to block.  When the user tries to drag this row on top of other table, I would like the small circle with diagonal line to appear.

This is a working example that demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.swing.DropMode;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class JTableDnD extends JFrame 
{

    private JTable tableA;
    private JTable tableB;

    public JTableDnD() 
    {           
        // *** Create First Table ***

        List<Object[]> dataA = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        dataA.add(new Object[] {"A1", "A1"});
        dataA.add(new Object[] {"A2", "A2"});
        dataA.add(new Object[] {"A3", "A3"});

        List<String> columnsA = new ArrayList<String>();
        columnsA.add("Column 1");
        columnsA.add("Column 2");

        tableA = new JTable(new TableModel(columnsA, dataA));

        tableA.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        tableA.setDragEnabled(true);
        tableA.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT_ROWS);
        tableA.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        tableA.setTransferHandler(new TableTransferHandler(tableA));

        JScrollPane scrollPaneA = new JScrollPane(tableA);

        // *** Create Second Table ***

        List<Object[]> dataB = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        dataB.add(new Object[] {"B1", "B1"});
        dataB.add(new Object[] {"B2", "B2"});
        dataB.add(new Object[] {"B3", "B3"});

        List<String> columnsB = new ArrayList<String>();
        columnsB.add("Column 1");
        columnsB.add("Column 2");

        tableB = new JTable(new TableModel(columnsB, dataB));

        tableB.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        tableB.setDragEnabled(true);
        tableB.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT_ROWS);
        tableB.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        tableB.setTransferHandler(new TableTransferHandler(tableB));

        JScrollPane scrollPaneB = new JScrollPane(tableB);

        // *** Add ScrollPanes to Panel ***

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(scrollPaneA);

        JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();
        emptyPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 200));
        add(emptyPanel);

        add(scrollPaneB);

    }  // end JTableDnD constructor

    private static void createAndShowGUI() 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JTableDnD();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                createAndShowGUI(); 

            }

        });
    }
}


interface Reorderable 
{
    public void reorder(int from, int to);
}


class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements Reorderable
{

    private List<String> columnNames;
    private List<Object[]> data;

    public TableModel(List<String> columnNames, List<Object[]> data) 
    {
        super();
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void reorder(int from, int to) 
    {
        if (from < to)
        {
            to--;
        }

        Object[] row = data.remove(from);

        data.add(to, row);

        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() 
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
        return columnNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) 
    {
        return columnNames.get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
    {
        return data.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
    }

}  // end TableModel


class TableTransferHandler extends TransferHandler 
{
    private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor = new ActivationDataFlavor(Integer.class, DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType, "Integer Row Index");

    private JTable table = null;


    public TableTransferHandler(JTable table) 
    {
        this.table = table;
    }


    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent component) 
    {
        return new DataHandler(new Integer(table.getSelectedRow()), localObjectFlavor.getMimeType());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) 
    {
        boolean b = support.getComponent() == table && 
                    support.isDrop() && 
                    support.isDataFlavorSupported(localObjectFlavor);

        table.setCursor(b ? DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop : DragSource.DefaultMoveNoDrop);

        return b;
    }


    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent component) 
    {
        return TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) 
    {
        JTable target = (JTable) support.getComponent();

        JTable.DropLocation dropLocation = (JTable.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();

        int index = dropLocation.getRow();

        int max = table.getModel().getRowCount();

        if (index < 0 || index > max)
        {
            index = max;
        }

        target.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

        try 
        {
            Integer rowFrom = (Integer) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(localObjectFlavor);

            if (rowFrom != -1 && rowFrom != index) 
            {
                ((Reorderable) table.getModel()).reorder(rowFrom, index);

                if (index > rowFrom)
                {
                    index--;
                }

                target.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(index, index);

                return true;
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void exportDone(JComponent component, Transferable transferable, int action) 
    {
        if (action == TransferHandler.MOVE) 
        {
            table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
    }
}  // end TableTransferHandler
```

I believe I need to add some extra logic to the canImport() method to make sure that the row that is being dropped is from that same table, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I've tried inspecting the data inside the TransferSupport object that gets passed into canImport(), but it does not seem to have any function that returns the exact JTable object source.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I've posted a full working example.  I've included separate table models and TransferHandlers for each JTable, so it looks like a lot of code, but some of it is duplicate.

Comment: *"but some of it is duplicate."*  Part of the idea of a ***Minimal*** Complete Tested and Readable Example is .. **not** to include duplicate code!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I shorted up the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplified Swing DnD, there is no support for getting at the source of the transferable. The component returned by TransferSupport` is the *target* of the drop, that is the component that somehow should handle the associated transferable. So if you have a per-component TransferHandler configured with a particular table, the support's component will always be that same table instance and your check will be true trivially.

If you want to enable/disable dropping based on the sender, you'll have to provide it on a per-drag basis: a drag starts in exportAsDrag and ends in exportDone, so you can set/null the sender in those.

```
@Override
protected void exportDone(JComponent component,
        Transferable transferable, int action) {
    table = null;
}

@Override
public void exportAsDrag(JComponent comp, InputEvent e, int action) {
    table = (JTable) comp;
    super.exportAsDrag(comp, e, action);
}
```

Now you can re-use the same instance of the handler across several instances of table:

```
TableTransferHandler handler = new TableTransferHandler();
tableA.setTransferHandler(handler);
tableB.setTransferHandler(handler);
```

As an aside: I wouldn't fiddle with the cursors, they are supporsed to be under complete control of the dnd subsystem.

Comment: This almost works, but when I drag a row to the other table and then release the mouse over that table, and then move the mouse back to the original table, it now shows the circle with diagonal line - over the original table!

Comment: can't reproduce - and actually don't quite understand what you mean: when you release the mouse anywhere outside the table, the drag is cancelled and the internals will switch the cursors back to normal. You removed your custom cursor handling, didn't you?

Comment: You're right - I forget to remove one of the custom cursor handling lines.  It works perfectly now!